# ldtp linux desktop testing platform and raspbian

Tags: raspbian, gui, perl

is using ldtp on raspbian possible using a language such as perl to control the gui?

i currently automate the win32 chrome browser gui using perl (win32::guitest) and would like to use a pi instead.

your help is appreciated. thanks,
-Jer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*LDTP* (Linux Desktop Testing Project) is part of the Raspbian repository. You can show it with `apt show ldtp` and install it with `sudo apt install ldtp`. *perl* is also part of the default Raspbian image. So if *perl* and *ldtp* does not have limitations by itself then it should be able to control the graphical user interface with them.